# Installing Git 1.9.5 on Windows 10

Tags: git, windows-10

Is anybody else having trouble installing Git 1.9.5 on Windows 10 Pro? After numerous restarts, it still will not do anything. E.g., I click the exe - wait, the Windows load pointer shows. Continue waiting. Nothing.

Has anybody managed to install it successfully?

Comment: Same problem here. Running it in Windows 7 backward compatibility mode worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Since Git isn't codesigned, Windows is trying to look it up against a corpus of known good (but unsigned) installers.  It downloads the entire list of data (rather than send information about what you're installing to Microsoft.)  You can wait (don't restart!) for this data to download *or* you can disable this scan.

It should be in Settings > Update & Security > Windows Defender.  Turn off the Real-time Protection and Cloud-based Protection options, then you should be able to install without a delay.

Comment: Note that I'm only *pretty sure* that these are the right settings, since I've got that big list of signatures already, so I can't repro this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue, followed Matteo's suggestion, except I was able to install it with Windows 8 compatibility turned on.